# Анализ строк с использованием regexp

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте!

Есть задача: в строке нужно найти слова последняя буква которых совпадает с первой буквой следующего слова. Я так понял, проще всего данную задачу решить при помощи регулярок, но, немного изучив синтаксис регулярных выражений, я так и не нашёл способ указания "одинаковости" подстроки или символа. Подскажите пожалуйста, как лучше решить данную задачу.

P.s. Строка берётся из файла, т.е. их(слов) может быть сколь угодно много.

Comment: "Сколь угодно много" для регулярных выражений плохо. Проц и память, конечно, железные, но... А одинаковость -- заключаете последнюю букву в скобки (получается группа) и ссылаетесь на неё далее в шаблоне `\1`
(если такое есть в java. В perl compatible (т.е. почти везде) оно есть.

Comment: Спасибо, будем разбираться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде как-бы вот ( JS ):

```
re = /\b\w*(\w)\b(?=\W+\b\1)/g;
str = 'a1d d2a b3d d4b b5a';

while ( ( res = re.exec( str ) ) != null ) console.log( res[0] );

//a1d, b3d, d4b
```

P.S: могут возникнуть проблемы с не английскими символами

Comment: Возможно, кроме ключика /g -- поиск всех, будет нужен ещё и ключик /m -- многострочный поиск

Answer (score 3):

Используйте [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) и [MatchResult](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/MatchResult.html). Как правильно указал alexlz, надо использовать группы, которые в Java, конечно же, есть, хоть синтаксис и не perl-compatible. И вам, вероятно, понадобится метод [find с параметром](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28int%29).

И почитайте [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: @cy6erGn0m вернулся из отпуска и отправился на охоту.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение